# Execute "Run line" commands from command prompt or batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am writing a simple program to access samba shares in batch. I know how to access a samba share using "\(SERVER_NAME)" in the "RUN Line", but I don't know how I would go about doing that in batch.

Comment: If you're referring to the `Run` dialog accessed by pressing Windows + R on the GUI, the `START` command does exactly that: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: `\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext` is known as UNC (Universal Naming Convention). CMD supports this. See `dir \\127.0.0.1\C$\windows`.

Comment: Another way to get an Explorer window is to use ´explorer.exe \\server\share´ or temporarily assign a drive letter with `PushD \\Server\share` it vanishes when issuing a `PopD` this is haleful for apps which can't deal with UNC's themselves.